EnumWindows function enumerates only top-level windows
EnumWindows() is described as

Enumerates all top-level windows on the screen by passing the handle to each window [...]

What does Microsoft mean by "top-level"?
Say I have an application like Word and Word displays a message box. From a Z-order perspective, the message box is "top-level". However, from a hierarchy perspective, the Word main window is "top-level", because it is the parent of the message box. So, which one does Microsoft mean?

Well, obviously, "top level" is with respect to the hierarchy, not with respect to the Z-order.

So, for each top-level window you need to enumerate all of its owned windows if you want to list all windows.  In doing so, you will find more caveats with terminology:  be sure you understand what is the difference between the "owner" and the "parent" of a window.

I think MessageBox is an exception, as that would be WS_POPUP, while WS_CHILD windows exclude both WS_POPUP and top-level windows. I don't know how WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW would be considered - and I'm also unsure when a top-level window wouldn't have WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW. Have fun finding out though!

"the Word main window is "top-level", because it is the parent of the message box." - It is the owner, not the parent. Those are different concepts. @Dai The rules are pretty simple: A top-level window is a window that doesn't have a parent, or doesn't have an owner, or whose owner is the desktop window.
